# How to bind Visibility to element which is passed as parameter in User Control?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I have `User control` which looks like this:

```
public partial class TopBarUserControl : UserControl
{
    public System.Windows.Visibility menuVisibility { get; set; }

    public TopBarUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And I render it in my other page with:

```
<local:TopBarUserControl />
```

It works fine but I want to hide some part of my Control. So I pass the parameter to control with:

```
<local:TopBarUserControl menuVisibility="Collapsed" />
```

But I don't know how to make it works fine (hide my elements).
**What I have tried:**

in xaml control:

```
Visibility="{Binding menuVisibility}"
```

or set it in `code behind` but I don't know where it should be setted.

Comment: You need to make a dependency property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things here, first you should ideally declare the property as a `DependencyProperty`, so you can bind against it and get automatic change notification to update the UI at the right time. Then, you need to correct the binding, so that it points to the property declared at the `UserCoontrol` level (as you wrote it, it binds to the `DataContext`, which may not be set.

Try this, in XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.TopBarUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             x:Name="MainControl">   <!--Give a XAML name to the whole control to bind to properties declared in code-behind-->

    <Menu Visibility="{Binding ElementName=MainControl, Path=MenuVisibility}"/>
</UserControl>
```

Notice the binding has an `ElementName` matching the `x:Name` at the control level.
The convert your property to `DependencyProperty`:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class TopBarUserControl : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MenuVisibilityProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MenuVisibility", typeof(Visibility), typeof(TopBarUserControl), null);

        public Visibility MenuVisibility
        {
            get { return (Visibility)GetValue(MenuVisibilityProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MenuVisibilityProperty, value); }
        }

        public TopBarUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```